# Find extremums for u(x,y)

Tags: calculus

I am not able to calculate extremums for the given function:
$u = 3x^2 - 3xy + 3x +y^2 + 5y$

I am able to calculate
$ 
u_x = 6x - 3y+ 3
$

$
u_{xx} = 6
$

$
u_{xy} = -3 = u_{yx}
$

$
u_y = -3x + 2y + 5
$

$
u_{yy} = 2
$

But what is next? Where are extremum points?

Comment: You may want to start with finding all *stationary points*, i.e. solutions to the system of equations: $u'_x = 0$, $u'_y = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u$ is differentiable, any local min/max point $(x,y)$ must satisfy $Du(x,y)=0$. You've already done the calculations, so just solve \begin{align}
6x-3y+3&=0 \\
-3x+2y+5&=0
\end{align} to get a single point $(x_0,y_0)$. The matrix representing $D^2u(x_0,y_0)$ (i.e. the "Hessian matrix") is $$H=\begin{bmatrix}6 & -3 \\ -3 & 2\end{bmatrix},$$ as you've calculated. Clearly $\det(H)>0$, so $D^2u(x_0,y_0)$ is positive definite. Then apply the higher derivative test to deduce that $u$ has a local minimum at $(x,y)$.

(In fact, this is a global minimum, since the fact that $D^2u$ is positive definite everywhere implies that $u$ is convex.)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

$$u_x=6x-3y+3=0 \to y= 2x+1$$
$$u_y=-3x+2y+5=0$$

Substitution leads to 
$$-3x+2(2x+1)+5=0 \to x=-7, y=-13$$

Which is the global minimum since both $u_{xx},u_{yy}>0$

Comment: btw, it is y = -13

Comment: Apparently the hardest step, fixed.